# change html attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code.

```
<li class="source" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="content1" title="" data-original-title="Test">Test Server 1</li>
```

I'm trying to change the content of data-original-title using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('content1').style["data-original-title"] = 'Online';
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
document.getElementById('content1').dataset.originalTitle = 'Online';
```

```html
<li class="source" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="content1" title="" data-original-title="Test">Test Server 1</li>
```

or [`.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
document.getElementById('content1').setAttribute('data-original-title', 'Online');
```

```html
<li class="source" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="content1" title="" data-original-title="Test">Test Server 1</li>
```

Comment: Nice use of `dataset`!

Answer (score 1):

`data-original-title` is an attribute, so you would need to set it as such:

```
document.getElementById('content1').setAttribute('data-original-title','Online');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setAttribtute()`

```
document.getElementById("content1").setAttribute("data-original-title", "Online");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
document.getElementById('content1').dataset.originalTitle = 'Online';
```

```html
<li class="source" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="content1" title="" data-original-title="Test">Test Server 1</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be a style, try this:

```
document.getElementById('content1').data-original-title = 'Online';
```

Comment: I'm really doubting JavaScript will correct parse the `-`, and will rather try to read them as a subtraction.

Comment: You are right, better to use setAttribute() method.